# asp.net mvc child actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have worked with asp.net web forms a lot but this is my first ASP.Net MVC application. What I would like to do is use a child view to render some controls which are displayed and manipulated (relatively) independently of the page.

for example, say I have a calendar "gadget" that uses server side logic to display a list of events every time a date is clicked, completely independently of the processing on the rest of the page.

In web forms I could just create an ASCX (web user control). When a date is clicked in the control, the whole page is posted back but I can just put the click handling inside the calendar control; the rest of the page is round-tripped automatically without having to put in any specific logic to handle the calendar control's postback.

with MVC if I route the "date clicked" action to a calendar controller, this has no knowledge of the page it's embedded in so it can only draw the calendar, not the rest of the page. The only workaround I can think of (apart from ajax) is to have the owning page's controller handle all the calendar click actions and passing them onto the calendar controller before rendering the view for the whole page

Hopefully I've missed something obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Look at Partial Views and RenderAction.

Here are some URLS to get you started

http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/11/24/renderpartial-vs-renderaction.aspx

Comment: Yes, this.  Also if you need to reuse the layout like a master page, try building a template, it's essentially the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've looked at the URLs and read up a bit more but there is still something missing for me. I understand how partial views and child actions can be used to render the view for the calendar control initially but what happens when a date in the calendar is clicked? This click action should presumably be sent to the calendar controller (so it can retrieve items on that date), but the calendar controller can't render the rest of the page can it?. All the examples I've seen of child views generate only static content or navigation links, not "postback" controls

Comment: You might have to look into using ajax to just update that calendar part of the page

Comment: @Andy - Daniel is right. Your still thinking like a webforms developer, there is no code behind. All "clicks" point to a URL not a code behind method. So you can post a form to a URL or call ajax on a URL (controller action)

Comment: OK thanks. I'd done a bit more reading and come to the conclusion that ajax might be the only solution. I'm very familiar with the guts of http etc and know just how much 'magic' ig going on behind the scenes to prop up the web form ascx postback thing. But obviously it's still difficult to give up something that makes this case so easy to handle.

Answer (score -9):

You could use an iframe to display the calendar within the main page.  Your main page can have the URL `http://example.com/main` and the iframe can have URL `http://example.com/calendar/today`.  By setting the `target` attribute on links, a link inside the iframe can reload just the iframe, or can reload the main page.  Likewise, a link on the main page can target the iframe.

Since both the main page and the iframe would be coming from your server, there won't be any cross-domain issues, so you can do any scripting you need.